# Hover text for people reached

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

Hovering over the People Reached part of the profile page says:

> Estimated number of times people viewed your helpful posts
>   (based on page views of your **questions**
>   and **questions** where you wrote highly-ranked answers

Instead of **questions** and **answers**.

Comment: _Answers where you wrote highly-ranked answers_. That really doesn't make sense.

Comment: I'm marking this [tag:status-bydesign]. If you would like to change the wording, please ask on [meta.se].

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It says "questions and questions where you wrote highly-ranked answers".

Read it as "(questions) and (questions where you wrote highly-ranked answers)", not as "(questions and questions) where you wrote highly-ranked answers".

Note the **where you wrote highly-ranked answers**. Maybe that part should be marked as bold or something to make it clearer.

Answers does not have page views, but questions where you write answers have page views, and it is those that are counted.

Comment: Thanks for clarifyng, it feels obvious now :)